# Optimizing a Ruby on Rails Project

Tags: ruby-on-rails, optimization, yaml

I'm busy creating a very simplistic *ruby on rails* app that won't need a lot things that are loaded in the ruby on rails environment by default.

I won't be using **mysql**, just one model that fetches data from a Yaml file. So I'm thinking I won't be needing **ActiveRecord**, or at least a large part of it. ( Correct me if I'm wrong here );

How do I go about purging all the unneeded things from my app.
( Like stopping the **app** from looking in /config/database.yml for config which I won't need )

And, when I'm all done, how do I figure out what things are loaded, but not needed? example: **ActionMailer**.

Thanks,
Steve

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your environment.rb - File:

```
 # Skip frameworks you're not going to use. To use Rails without a database,
 # you must remove the Active Record framework.
 config.frameworks -= [ :active_record, :active_resource, :action_mailer ]
```